# Selberg trace formula, quadratic L-values, and generalization

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, trace-formula

It is known that the geometric side of the Selberg trace formula on GL(2) is related to values of quadratic L-functions (due to Sarnak, Zagier, etc).

Are there any conjectures or results about its generalization to other groups, such as GL(3) and GL(n)?

Comment: Do you mean the point that volumes of various compact geodesics are often equal to values of L-functions at $s=1$? Langlands' old work on the residue at the first pole of minimal-parabolic Eisenstein series relates that to the natural volume of the arithmetic quotient, for example. And by this year many other "periods" of Eisenstein series are understood as giving L-functions (although this is not the typical case, in some sense).

Comment: to paul garrett Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: to paul garrett the situation for the residue of Eisenstein series is quite different from that of geometric side of trace formulas. I am looking for the connection between geometric side of trace formula on GL(n) and certain special values of certain L-functions.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you are looking for, then yes, a fair amount of work has been done.  [Deitmar and Hoffman](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310372) use a simple trace formula on SL(3) to get asymptotics of class number of cubic orders, which can also be interpreted as a prime geodesic theorem.  This is a higher-dimensional analogue of quadratic class numbers (which can be viewed as special $L$-values) appearing in a trace formula for SL(2).  Deitmar also treats higher rank analogues in other papers.

Another way in which zeta/$L$-functions  arise in the geometric side of trace formulas (maybe not what you are looking for, but perhaps still interesting) is discussed in general in [this paper of Hoffman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.8673) and for Sp(4) in [his joint paper with Wakatsuki](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0541).  Namely, one gets Shintani zeta functions arising as coefficients in the unipotent geometric terms of the Arthur-Selberg trace formula.